# JSTree: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jstree is not a function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, jstree

I use this piece of code o=in my ASP.NET Core application:

```
<head>
    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>
    <script src='~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jstree/jstree.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/jstree/themes/default/style.min.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<div id="container2">
<script>
            $(function () {
                $('#container2').jstree({
                        'core': {
                            'data': [
                                {
                                    "text": "Root node", "children": [
                                        { "text": "Kind node 1" },
                                        { "text": "Kind node 2" },
                                        { "text": "Kind node 3" }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    });
            });
        </script>
```

When I run the project in VS as IISExpress app it works.
But If I run it as an desktop app I receive the error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jstree is not a function

What is wrong in the code?

Comment: Did you check if the jstree file loaded successfully? Check the Network tab in your browser's tools as you load the page.

Comment: My app is NET Core+ElectronNet Desktop app. When I run it in VS as an IISExpress - it works correctly in Browser. But when run it as an app I receive the errors

Comment: well I don't know Electron at all, but I would guess maybe the file isn't accessible to the electron app. Maybe the path is wrong, or the file didn't get included in the build or something. You'd have to check. The code on its own doesn't give much of a clue - if it works in one environment but not another then the culprit is usually the environment rather than the code.